# multiprocessing starmap AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: multiprocessing, anaconda, python-3.6, nonetype, starmap

My parallelized script was working for a while. I used the `multiprocessing` library and the function `starmap` for it. But now when I'm trying to run it the following `AttributeError`is displayed:

```
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 
16:13:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 6.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-d3a2b861c70a>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('E:/Python/E2Oeval.py', wdir='E:/Python')

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "E:/Python/E2Oeval.py", line 1227, in <module>
df_Qobs_percs, df_Qsim_percs, df_sdQsim_percs, df_KGE_alpha, df_KGE_beta, df_KGE_r = ee.main_par(db_Qobs_meta_dir, Ens_mean_dir, Ens_sd_dir, db_Qobs_dir)

File "E:/Python/E2Oeval.py", line 835, in main_par
res = p.starmap(self.main, subsets)

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 274, in starmap
return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()

File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
raise self._value

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

The error only occurs on windows, for unix the code is working. I need to run it on the windows machine since it requires some CPU power which is not given by notebook. Has anyone an idea how to detect the `NoneType` object causing the error?